# HTML5,css,Javascript,PHP Auto-complete IDE

Tags: html, ide, autocomplete, html5-canvas

Is there an IDE that pops auto-complete for  HTML5 (especially canvas), Javascript,JQuery library, php and css syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Try [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit):

> PHP, Python, Ruby, JavaScript, Perl, Tcl, XML, HTML 5, CSS 3? Yes,
>   with (customizable) syntax coloring, folding, background syntax
>   checking, and excellent auto-complete and calltips (we call it "code
>   intelligence").